# Automatically verify my website's links are pointing to urls that exist?

Tags: testing

Is there a tool to automatically search through my site and test all the links? I hate running across bad urls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Xenu link sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) is excellent (and free)

Comment: PERFECTION! PERFECTION PERFECTION!

Answer (score 2):

[w3.org checklink](http://validator.w3.org/checklink)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd check out the [W3C Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work: http://www.dead-links.com/

Do google searches for "404 checker" or "broken link checker"

Answer (score 0):

I used Xenu's Link Sleuth in the past. It will crawl your site and tell you which links point to nowhere. It is not super fancy but it works.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenu%27s_Link_Sleuth

The Wikipedia page lists a whole bunch of other products.

Answer (score 0):

[WebHTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/21/fr/index.html)

Can take a long time to go through a large web site (I archived a 250MB website and it took approximately 2 hours - it wasn't local though) It has a log so you should be able to track 404s easily.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out Google's webmaster tools.

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

They give you the ability to see the 404's that GoogleBot discovers when crawling your website (along with lots and lots of other stuff).